# Adding a Network Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, modem, switch

My current system has a 'media panel' with a wireless modem and home pre-wired RJ45 cabling. The WAN/LAN port has a cable from the main fiber optic box and 4 ports that distribute the signal to 4 rooms in the house. However, I need to connect to 6 rooms.

I would like to connect a Netgear 5 port switch to get the additional 2 port connectivity.

Do I use one of the ports from modem (out) to the switch (in) and, then connect the pre-wired 2 additional rooms to the switch?
**How do I connect the switch to the modem?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you're describing as a modem is actually a combination modem + router.  Modems usually only have one Ethernet port (sometimes two).

Also, switches don't have any designated "in" or "out" ports; they just (to use an overly simple description) connect everything to everything.

So yes, what you'd do is connect any port of the switch to a port on the router, and then connect the remaining rooms to the switch.

Keep in mind that this can create a bit of a bottleneck, but if you're using gigabit hardware, this probably won't be an issue.  The only likely scenarios where this could be a problem is if you have a gigabit internet connection (like Google Fiber) or you have a NAS/file server.  In the second case, you'd want to either put both the NAS and the rooms using the NAS on the switch, or you'd want to put them on the router.  It's when they're on opposite sides of the switch that there's a bottleneck.  (I can draw a diagram if necessary; just ask.)

Comment: *switches don't have any designated "in" or "out" ports*...[some do](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-uplink-port-817724) (though this is much less common today in the past).

Comment: @Twisty Isn't that just about crossover cables?  If so, those are mostly obsolete; they're seldom required for fast ethernet, and never required for gigabit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: You are correct. I mentioned this because even the unlikely existence of such ports makes the statement *"switches don't have [these] ports"* incomplete.

Comment: Fair enough, fair enough.

Answer (score -1):

You've got it right, just use one of the modem's outs into the switch and then connect three rooms to the switch.

Comment: @Ramhound Why do you think this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: I fail to see how this differs from the other answer given, it just excludes all of the assumptions.  From the other answer, "So yes, what you'd do is connect any port of the switch to a port on the router, and then connect the remaining rooms to the switch."